# XCode inherit from module option is disabled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

Objective: I'm trying to set a custom `UITableViewController` class to my `tableviewcontroller` in the storyboard but then I noticed module is disabled and I don't see the custom file in the Class dropdown.

Earlier I could click the drop down and select my class file. I can confirm that the class file is inherited from `UITableViewController` (it should work fine with `UIViewController` as well)

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
```

Setup:

I'm working in a workspace and I've two SingleViewApp within this workspace, I suspect the option got disabled as soon as I added the 2nd project to the workspace. Not sure if this should impact.

Please advise with explanation.

**P.S.** It's enabled once I open the sub-project directly in XCode (outside workspace)

[image]